# Multiple Image Selection not working in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I tried using react native image crop picker library, but I am not able to integrate it in my project as it keeps giving error "**null is not an object (evaluating ImagePicker.openPicker)**"

Comment: Please mention your version of the image picker also the version of the react-native.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: You get this error message generally when you don't link your library. Check that you followed all linking steps in the library docs

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am running into the same issue currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well with React Native. The solution is that in your

```
ios/{appName}/info.plist
```

at the top of that file, make sure that your target number:

```
"platform :ios, '10.0'"
```

is the same as the target number that is found in Xcode:

```
Select your Project in the left navigator in XCode => Select the "General" tab => look under "Deployment Info" => "Target"
```

Mine weren't matching so I made them match at 10.0 respectively and now the package is no longer null, and is working perfectly